# Create Customer Groups from frontend after login or registration

Tags: magento2.2

I want to create customer groups from frontend i.e. if customer is logged in or registered then he can click on "Create Customer Group" option in account dashboard.

In "Create Customer Group" option the user have to fill up custom form containing the group details i.e. Group name, Group icon etc... and after filling all the information he can click on create group option in order to create new group.

I have managed to create customer groups but still not able get and save the custom fields mentioned above.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where you want to save these custom fields? In custom table? I think whenever you create any customer group in Magento, it only takes group Name and tax class. So where you are trying to save these custom fields?

Comment: Currently i am trying to save these custom fields in customer_group table. Yes by default magento only takes group name and tax class. I need these custom fileds in frontend on create group form as well as in backend.

Comment: So are you able to new fields in Admin Customer Group Grid? To debug put direct values of custom customer group fields in DB for 1 customer group and load it using 
 Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($id) print the output and check if you are getting custom field values or not

Comment: I think the above code given is of magento 1. I am working with magento 2.

Comment: you can follow this link to get customer group collection

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-customer-groups/